# Как сохранить значение из dateTimePicker в поле таблицы localdb

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-localdb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте! Есть windows forms приложение для работы с localdb , в поле date дата вводится вручную в текстбокс.Хочу добавить dateTimePicker для более удобного ввода даты. Как правильно описать элемент dateTimePicker, чтоб значение в поле date бралось из него, конкретно в моём коде? Заранее благодарю.

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label18.Visible)
            label18.Visible = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox9.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox9.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox10.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox10.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox11.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox11.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox12.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox12.Text))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Sale] (product, employee, customer, date)VALUES(@product, @employee, @customer, @date)", sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("product", textBox9.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("employee", textBox10.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer", textBox11.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", textBox12.Text);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            label18.Visible = true;
            label18.Text = "Все поля должны быть заполнены!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`DateTimePicker.Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DateTimePicker_Value)? Или вопрос в чем-то другом?

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", dateTimePicker.Value); - попробуйте так.

Comment: Ну и по традиции: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) - советую почитать.